# Pass partial view data to parent view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am new to `MVC` so I'm not sure if my question even makes sense.

I have several search pages that share the same search parameters and search result, so I thought I made a `Partial View` for this and render on different `Pages/Views`.  My problem is I do not know how to pass result data back to the `Parent View` after each search.  The `Parent View` just needs to take the result and render it so `Partial` and `Parent` views have the same `model`.

Can someone give me a direction on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass data from `partial` to you `parent` view.

`Partial` view shouldn't contain any logic, the only aim is to *render* something, that can be used on multiple pages.

I assume that in your case you need to have 2 pages (views), and each page can use the same `partial` view to render the same type of data (e.g. list of users).
You should pass your model (e.g. list of users) from your view to your `partial` view, as follows:

```
@Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName", Model)
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that the `Partial`and `Parent` views can use the same `Model`.

See Example bellow of how you could do it.

`_PartialView` uses a `Model` which renders in `ActionResult Index()` of the `Controller` and returns `View(model);`

When you submit the search you put the search parameters into the `Model` and pass it to the `Controller`. E.G. you will post it to `ActionResult Search(Model model)`. This `ActionResult` will go get the result, then you update the `Model` and return `View(model);`.